# Apache Camel: Do I need to make my FTP-Consumer route transactional?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have these FTP endpoint properties:

```
include=.*.xml&delay=60s&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&binary=true&move=.done&soTimeout=300000
```

So an endpoint need to search every 60 secounds the *.xml files and consume it. After that the files will be proceed and moved in 'done' directory.

I'm afraid that if f.e. by doing the move of a file an IOException occures, the file will already be deleted from the endpoint root directory.

The question is: do I need to make my FTP-Consumer route transactional?

Another question is: can you give an advise to add another usefull ftp consumer properties for this case?

Answer (score 0):

> if f.e. by doing the move of a file an IOException occures

According to [GenericFileEndpoint.java](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/file/GenericFileEndpoint.html) you can use `setMoveFailed()` to define where to move the file if the moving fails. 
The FTP endpoint should inherit that option, see here: [FtpEndpoint](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.8.0/camel-ftp/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/FtpEndpoint.html)

I do not think that you need to make you endpoint transactional.

Comment: If you don't know what is a transactional route see: http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html

Comment: "I do not think that you need to make you endpoint transactional." Can you please give an explanation?

Comment: Your are afraid that the file could be deleted and then some error might occur during the processing, **before** the file gets moved. It would be lost.
Using the setter you can define where to copy the file if an error occurs, therefore your file would not be lost.
Consequently, **in my opinion** no other action should be required.